# C# FP: Validation and execution with error handling functional way - space for improvement?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, option-type, either

I'm new to functional way of thinking in C# (well... not limited to language). Let's say there's method:

```
T LoadRecord<T>(int id)
```

### Concept

#### 1. Validation

When invalid input is given, I should return something like `Either<IEnumerable<ValidationError>, T>`.

#### 2. Execution

When calling DB/API/... which could throw, I should return `Either<Exception, T>`.

#### 3. Some or none record

Because entry may or may not exist I'm returning `Option<T>`.

### Final signature

If you combine all above, you end up with this:

```
Either<IEnumerable<ValidationError>, Either<Exception, Option<T>> LoadRecord<T>(int id)
```

I can introduce types such as:

- `Validation<T>` (~ `: Either<IEnumerable<ValidationError>, T>`)
- `Result<T>` (~ `: Either<Exception, T>`)

Now, signature of my method would look like:

```
Validation<Result<Option<T>>> LoadRecord<T>(int id)
```

### Usage

```
return LoadRecord<User>(1).Match(
           vl => BadRequest(),
           vr => vr.Match(
                     el => StatusCode(500),
                     er => er.Some(u => Ok(u))
                             .None(NotFound());
```

### Imperative implementation

```
try
{
    var u = LoadRecord<User>(id);
    if (u == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(u);
}
catch (ValidationException)
{
    return BadRequest();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return StatusCode(500);
}
```

### Question

As you can see signature of method is still quite odd - at first sight it gives you "validation", but I'm really asking for `T`. Usage is also not very pretty looking, but indeed more concise than imperative one.

Is this correct approach? Is there way how to improve signature/readability of code?

Comment: Maybe you can convert validation error to exception, or convert exception and validation error to unified error code. This makes function signature simpler.

Comment: It's a good start. I think the best you can do is further specialize the generics away. `OptionResult<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well, yeah. Depending upon the complexity involved, a modern (C# 7 I guess) tuple might be sufficient: `(bool failed, T result)`. The limitation is that there is no methods responsible for proper chaining - `fmap`ing in terms of Haskell - your containers (better to say, however not quite theoretically correct - your `Functor`s and, less frequently, your `Monad`s).
2. `Either<IEnumerable<ValidationError>, Either<Exception, Option<T>> LoadRecord<T>(int id)` - nah. Observe your signature: **as for the `TFail`**, you either get an `IEnumerable<ValidationError>` or `Exception`; so, technically, you need an `Exception | IEnumerable<ValidationError>` type there, thought it will take quite a bit of boilderplate coding to implement in the `C#`. Same applies to the `Option<T>` part, which represents a successful result: you don't need `IOption` to be returned; even if it is there, your **implementation** is responsible to unwrap successful result and just spit out `T`, or report an `TFail` error through the `Either` mechanism. As a conclusion: yeah, containers are great, but avoid endless nesting: **there is time to wrap things and there is time to unwrap them: feel the moment**.
3. The last but far no the least: exception handling should be delegated to the containers themselves. `Rx` is a good example: it asks you for the `onError: Action<Exception>` lambda, which is invoked when exception is captured. Thus you let your client customize desired behavior, rather than hardcode it once. More than that, as your particular example is specific, `IOption` is a way to handle error, so in your particular case - **but not as a general rule** - no `onError` needed: just swallow an exception and return `Nothing`.